How to read csv with binary delimiter
The source csv file is:
123456TextValue1
654321TextValue2

where 123456 and TextValue1 are different values, separated by binary delimiter (\u0001)
Similary 654321 TextValue2
I use ConvertRecord for updating the delimiter from "\u0001" to ";"
RecordReader is CSVReader with the following properties:

Schema Access Strategy: Use 'Schema Text' Property
Schema Text: #{text_schema}
Value Separator: \u0001
Treat First Line as Header: false
Ignore CSV Header Column Names: true

RecordWriter is CSVRecordSetWriter:

Schema Access Strategy: Use 'Schema Text' Property
Schema Text: #{text_schema}
Value Separator: ;
Include Header Line: true

text_schema is
 {
  "type": "record",
  "name": "test_schema",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "FIELD_1",
      "type": ["int","null"],
    "description": "FIELD_1"
  },
  {
    "name": "FIELD_2",
    "type": ["string","null"],
    "description": "FIELD_2"
  }
 ]
}

Expected output is:
   FIELD_1;FIELD_2;
   123456;TextValue1
   654321;TextValue2

But I got the following error:
ERROR
ConvertRecord[id=01931001-0d7e-1e43-146d-1a380e6d43b7] Failed     to process FlowFile[filename=7365b509-7100-4bc2-a070-    4cc8ce8377b9]; will route to failure:     org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: Could not     parse incoming data
   Caused by:                   org.apache.nifi.serialization.MalformedRecordException: Error                  while getting next record
  Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:       "123456TextValue1"


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

@Jelly, are you sure there is a delimiter between fields? because i don't see it on a screenshot.

Yes, it is binary delimiter. One significant byte as delimiter - so it can't be displayed.

try to set as delimiter this expression: ${literal('&#01;'):unescapeXml()}

daggett,  do you mean to use ${literal('�'):unescapeXml()} as a dilimiter value? If it is so, I tried it, but the same error received

i have concern that you have this delimiter in your cvs file. normally you can see the character with code 1 in console and on web-ui.

I used ${literal('\u0001'):unescapeXml()}  as a value of Value Separator in CSVReader.     Where could I see the delimiter in web-ui?  For example, in failure-queue on ConvertRecord I have not still saw it.
